# should I DeleteGlobalRef if the jobject is returning from JNI to JAVA?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I want to store a java object in JNI. So I do

```
jobject gRefObj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);
```

After that I want to get back the jobject from other thread and from java call to jni to return object. So I do.

```
(*_env)->DeleteGlobalRef(_env, gRefObj ); // if remove this line, it will work
return gRefObj; // From jni return to java
```

Then I got classCastException, but if I remove the DeleteGlobalRef, it working fine. Will java delete it after use?

Comment: Why did you tagged java, c++ and C?

Comment: dude, it's jni and java, it contains c

Comment: Technically your global object could be destroyed by the `DeleteGlobalRef`. Does it work if you first create a local ref with `NewLocalRef` passing in your global ref and then call `DeleteGlobalRef`on your global ref before returning the local one?

Comment: @mkaes, I haven't tried yet, but I still need to deleteLocalRef right?

Comment: @Oktaheta: No. _"Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call. They are freed automatically after the native method returns [to Java]"_. If, however, you do _not_ return to Java (i.e. you're on a purely native thread), then you need to delete any local references created on that thread yourself.

Comment: Yup, it works fine, I pass to NewLocalRef and deleteGlobalRef. After that I return localRefObject, I assumed that java will delete after use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @mkaes and @Michael comment, i've tried to do

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_sample_getMyObject(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass clz = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    // .. doing something
    jobject lRefObj = (*env)->NewLocalRef(env, gRefObj);

    (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, gRefObj);  
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, clz);
    return lRefObj;
}
```